# Apply a prop to a Cloned Child that is invoked by React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following React Router Setup in Parent. I needed to pass props to `MyProfile`, so i passed as function:

```
render() {


    return (
        <Router history={ browserHistory }>
            <Route path={ "/" } component={ Home }>
                <IndexRoute component={ PropertyList } />
                <Route path={ "propertylist" } component={ PropertyList } />
                <Route path={ "property" } component={ Property } />
                <Route path={ "myprofile" } component={() => <MyProfile logo={ this.state.companyLogo } userPic={ this.state.userPic } /> } />
            </Route> 
        </Router>
    )
}
```

But in my child. I am also trying to append with a prop containing a state as an object to a clone.

```
<Col style={ style.wrapper } xs={ columns } sm={ columns } md={ columns }>
    {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { isMobile: this.state.isMobile })}
</Col>
```

The `isMobile: this.state.isMobile` is not being passed.

Comment: Instead of `React.cloneElement`, did you consider using a Higher order component? (usually referred as HOC). Cloning is extremely hacky, HOC are almost always a simpler solution.

Comment: is the `Col style...` snippet around the `Router` or around the `MyProfile` component?

Comment: @SimonBoudrias thank you Simon, this seems like the proper route to go.